# Blender animation not importing into Unreal Engine correctly

Tags: animation, .fbx, unreal-engine

I am currently trying to import animations into Unreal Engine that I've made for my character using Blender, but no matter what I do the animation doesn't seem to maintain the same sense of motion as it did when it was in Blender. Rather than the body moving down to the feet, the feet are moving up to the body. I've even used FBX Review to make sure that it's the same after exporting, and everything checks out until it's imported into UE.

I've provided some video of it below so you'll be able to understand it a bit better.

Is anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?
Thank you!

Blender Animation in Blender: https://youtu.be/-3a1haU_N7Y

Blender Animation in UE: https://youtu.be/eNo0z2ni360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your armature has a `root` bone that is the topmost parent of the entire bone hierarchy, and located in the world center with no rotation nor scale.

Most game engines use the root bone as reference for all animations. If you don't have one set correctly, it will either give you lots of errors when importing or mistakenly consider another bone as the root, which looks to be your case.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!